# Convert two numbers to a range

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I want to convert these two numbers into a range so that when I find a number between them, I can still find it.

My data:

```
[Column 1]     [Column 2]
Ticket Start   Ticket End 
000-000-001    000-000-005
```

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: 1. Your data doesn't seem to be numeric. 2. What do you mean by convert to a range? And how do you want to fund a number between them?

Comment: The data is the series number of the tickets used for the raffle promo. In the monitoring, the processors only encode from where the tickets start and end. For example, the loan amount is 100,000 equivalent to 5 tickets. The processor will then encode 000-000-001 for the ticket start column and the 000-000-005 for the ticket end column. Now, if a winner is selected and the ticket number falls in between of 000-000-001 and 000-000-005, say 000-000-003; I can't be able to find it since the processor only encodes from where the tickets begin and end.

Comment: May be what you could do is remove the dash (-)  from the two numbers using SUBSTITUTE function. Apply the same on ticket number to be searched, then use VALUE function to get pure numbers and check if the ticket in question falls between the two. This is based on an assumption that there will be no alphabets in Ticket Numbers ever.